# Parenthesize the third character of every word using sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to parenthesize the third character of every word in a text file using `sed`. I've tried manipulating:

```
sed 's/\(\b[A-Z]\)/\(\1\)/g' filename
```

This does what I need except, it parenthesizes the first character, not the third.

It gives me: "Welcome To The Geek Stuff" => "(W)elcome (T)o (T)he (G)eek (S)tuff"

What I want is: "Welcome To The Geek Stuff" => “We(l)come To Th(e) Ge(e)k St(u)ff”

How can I parenthesize the third character of each word?

Comment: That's not every third character, that's the third character of every word.

Comment: Every third character would be `We(l)co(m)e (T)o (T)he( )Ge(e)k (S)tu(f)f`

Answer (score 6):

This sed command must put every third character present in a word within parenthesis.

```
$ echo 'Welcome To The Geek Stuff' | sed 's/\b\([A-Z][a-z]\)\([a-z]\)/\1(\2)/g'
We(l)come To Th(e) Ge(e)k St(u)ff

$ echo 'Welcome To The Geek Stuff' | sed 's/\b\([a-z][a-z]\)\([a-z]\)/\1(\2)/gi'
We(l)come To Th(e) Ge(e)k St(u)ff
```

Add `i` modifier in-order to do a case-insensitive match.

Comment: since you're new to Stackoverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character ,vice-versa. So this `\b\([a-z][a-z]\)` ensures that it matches the first two letters in a word.Without `\b`, it would match any two letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
cat file
Hi, this is a test with some data.
```

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,a,"");if (a[3]~/[[:alpha:]]/) $i=substr($i,1,2)"("a[3]")"substr($i,4)}}1' file
Hi, th(i)s is a te(s)t wi(t)h so(m)e da(t)a.
```

It test if third letter in the word is an alphabetic character,
if so, recreate the word with `()` around third character.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\b\(.\B.\)\B\(.\)/\1(\2)/g' file
```

This looks for the second non-word boundary from the start of a word boundary and surrounds the following character with parens.